# UI doesn't show up in #Screen tab in Unity 4.6

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have just upgraded Unity to version 4.6 and tried to create a button by Create -> UI -> Button.
However, this button doesn't show up in #Screen tab but it does in Game tab.
Please look at the screen shoot below:

[image]

[image]

**Another question is:** The default width and height when creating a new button is 160 x 30. When I change the source image with my own image button, I have to change the width and height parameters in **rect transform**. Is there any faster way to **automatically** obtain new width and height based on the image which I insert?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before and here's a possible solution.

By default, the editor camera (Scene Tab) renders the World Space,
so your Canvas component's render mode should be set to "World Space".
The problem may only occur when you're trying to (or supposedly) render your UI in Screen Space - Overlay or Screen Space - Camera in the Canvas component.

So if you want to properly edit UI objects in the scene tab/window; **set the Canvas component's render mode to World Space**.

We don't have this problem in Unity 4.x before because I think Unity automatically renders any render mode from the Canvas component, however, that doesn't happen in Unity 5.x. I'm guessing it's either intentional that they do that or it's a bug on Unity UI feature.

Comment: I'm wondering why this answer has been chosen as the right answer! "Screen Space - Overlay" and "World Space" mode in the canvas are two totally different modes with different functionalities. Even if you get it show up in the Scene tab, it's still the wrong answer. It's like saying my car's aircon doesn't cool well, and then the mechanic say bring down your windows to get cool air from outside.

Comment: Because it works on his case :)
Can you elaborate and enlighten us more on why it is "still the wrong answer" and get over with the analogies because you're not really informative. It's like you're letting us walk in a dark alley with a flashlight then you suddenly turn it off. Oops.

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html Screen Space - Overlay: This render mode places UI elements on the screen rendered on top of the scene. If the screen is resized or changes resolution, the Canvas will automatically change size to match this. World Space: In this render mode, the Canvas will behave as any other object in the scene. UI elements will render in front of or behind other objects in the scene based on 3D placement. This is useful for UIs that are meant to be a part of the world. You can't really see any difference?

Comment: "We don't have this problem in Unity 4.x before because I think Unity automatically renders any render mode from the Canvas component, however, that doesn't happen in Unity 5.x. I'm guessing it's either intentional that they do that or it's a bug on Unity UI feature."

I know the difference, it's just Unity who's not showing the UI for editing in the scene tab at the time UnityUI is still new. It seems they fix that problem now by the way.

Answer (score 3):

First, double click the button in your hierarchy and see that it indeed does not show in the Scene view, excluding any kind of zoom problem. (By the way, I'm assuming you mean "Scene" and not "Screen", right?) Things in different cameras or canvases might have very different scales but appear correctly in the Game view. I don't know how used you are to Unity, so I'm sorry if this sounds obvious. :)

Next, **check the dropdown labeled "Layers" on top of Unity's editor**, to the right of the Play, Pause and Step buttons. See if the layer of your button (which in this case is "UI") is visible. It should have an open eye icon next to it.

Regarding your other question, after dragging your sprite to the Image component, you can press the "Set Native Size" button, which will set the size of your object to the dimensions of your Sprite. Regarding the new UI, I think this is as automatic as it gets. Note that "Set Native Size" will only appear if your Image type is set to Simple (probably what you want) or Filled in the component.